# How to add particular cities list autocomplete in search bar while typing and make it dynamic

Tags: javascript, search, bootstrap-4, location

I have created the find property bar using bootstrap and css but now i need to make it dynamic. Tried lot to add the property and make it autocomplete but none of my code is working fine. Can anyone help me out with this.

```
    
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                        
                                                                Search Location
                                                                
                                                                        Al Furjan
                                                                        JLT
                                                                        Marina
                                                                        Burj Khalifa
                                                                        
                                                                
                                                            
                                                        
                                                                Property type
                                                                
                                                                        Apartment
                                                                        Villa
                                                                        Penthouse
                                                                        Shop
                                                                        Office Space
                                                                        Townhouse
                                                                        
                                                                
                                                            
                                                            
                                                                    Price
                                                                
                                                            
                                                        
                                                                Bed Room
                                                                
                                                                        Studio
                                                                        01
                                                                        02
                                                                        03
                                                                        04
                                                                        05+
                                                                
                                                            
                                                        
                                                                Bath Room
                                                                
                                                                        01
                                                                        02
                                                                        03
                                                                        04
                                                                        05+
```

```
    <script>
        function collision($div1, $div2) {
            var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
            var w1 = 40;
            var r1 = x1 + w1;
            var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
            var w2 = 40;
            var r2 = x2 + w2;

            if (r1 < x2 || x1 > r2)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        // Fetch Url value 
        var getQueryString = function (parameter) {
            var href = window.location.href;
            var reg = new RegExp('[?&]' + parameter + '=([^&#]*)', 'i');
            var string = reg.exec(href);
            return string ? string[1] : null;
        };
        // End url 
        // // slider call
        $('#slider').slider({
            range: true,
            min: 20,
            max: 500,
            step: 1,
            values: [getQueryString('minval') ? getQueryString('minval') : 20, getQueryString('maxval') ?
                getQueryString('maxval') :500
            ],

            slide: function (event, ui) {

                $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(0) .price-range-min').html( ui.values[0] + 'K');
                $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(1) .price-range-max').html( ui.values[1] + 'K');
                $('.price-range-both').html('<i>K' + ui.values[0] + ' - </i>K' + ui.values[1]);

                // get values of min and max
                $("#minval").val(ui.values[0]);
                $("#maxval").val(ui.values[1]);

                if (ui.values[0] == ui.values[1]) {
                    $('.price-range-both i').css('display', 'none');
                } else {
                    $('.price-range-both i').css('display', 'inline');
                }

                if (collision($('.price-range-min'), $('.price-range-max')) == true) {
                    $('.price-range-min, .price-range-max').css('opacity', '0');
                    $('.price-range-both').css('display', 'block');
                } else {
                    $('.price-range-min, .price-range-max').css('opacity', '1');
                    $('.price-range-both').css('display', 'none');
                }

            }
        });

        $('.ui-slider-range').append('<span class="price-range-both value"><i>' + $('#slider').slider('values', 0) +
            ' - </i>' + $('#slider').slider('values', 1) + '</span>');

        $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(0)').append('<span class="price-range-min value">' + $('#slider').slider('values', 0) +
            'k</span>');

        $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(1)').append('<span class="price-range-max value">' + $('#slider').slider('values', 1) +
            'k</span>');
    </script>
```

How do i make my find button work properly

Comment: Remake your first code snippet, I think you selected the wrong language. It is rather hard to read.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.